# How to find out the time spent inside a PHP script?

Tags: php

I'm executing a PHP script that takes about a minute to finish and although the default time limit is set to 30 seconds, the script continues its execution after that limit.
I found out, that the limit only affects the time that is spent inside the script itself and not the time spent in library functions like database queries etc.

Is there a way to find out the time that is actually spent *inside* the script? I tried to use getrusage, but it doesn't seem to return the appropriate values for this problem.

Example:

```
<?php
$time = microtime(TRUE);
sleep(100);
echo 'Time: ', microtime(TRUE) - $time;
?>
```

The script waits for 100 seconds and does not terminate after the time limit of 30 seconds.
According to the documentation of set_time_limit, the time that is spent inside the *sleep* function (100 seconds) is not involved in the calculation of the execution time, because it's an external (library) function.

Comment: You can check time inside that script. Are you sure you want terminate execution in `hard` way, with fatal error?

Comment: No, I dont't want to terminate the execution. I just want to know how much of the execution time is spent inside my script and how much is spent in library functions.

Comment: what do you mean my "inside" the script and "lib functions"??? How does that 2 times differ? docs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`I just want to know how much of the execution time is spent inside my script and how much is spent in library functions.`

Use [XDebug Profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) for it.

Comment: You beat me to Xdebug by a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
<?php
// the whole operation
$time1 = time();

// perform some functions
$s = file_get_contents("somefilename");
$time2 = time();

// perform some library functions
$rs = some_third_party_library_function();
$time3 = time();

// Show results
echo "Overall Time spent: " . ($time3 - $time1) . "s <br>";
echo "Time spent reading file: ". ($time2 - $time1) . "s <br>";
echo "Time spent by Third Party Library: "  . ($time3 - $time2) . "s <br>";
?>
```

Comment: This is the same type of option provided in the answer by me but i dont understand what is the actual requirement of @ChristianK

Comment: the output that you are showing is in `ms` but the actual calculations are made in Seconds. Isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the start time before entering the script, then mark the end time after the script ends. Echo the difference then.

```
<?php
$a=time();
sleep(5);
$b=time();
echo $b-$a;
?>
```

Comment: That way, the total execution time is measured, but I would like to distinguish between the script and library functions.

Comment: Then could you please show some script samples? so that i can say where to use this technique.

Comment: I added an example to my question. :)

Comment: @ChristianK - The example that you added is in no way SEMANTICALLY different from my answer. Could you please explain what unique thing is there in your example?

Comment: @ChristianK - I provided the `sleep()` function just as a dummy thing to add some delay to the program. But the rest of the logic should be the same for calculating your `script execution time`.

Comment: The time that is measured and echo-ed by the examples differs from the actual execution time that PHP keeps track of. When you call sleep(100), the script is running for 100 seconds, but the execution time of the script (only the script without any external functions) would be almost zero (Total time minus sleep-time).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to measure the execution time of individual functions vs standard or built-in PHP functions, this is best done with a proper debugger and code profiler.  [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)  does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how complicated your script is, however you can just add a comment to all your library functions calls. If your code requires their returned values in order to be properly executed, replace them with constant values (that could have been returned by these functions). For example:

```
$result = mysql_query( ... )
```

replace with:

```
// $result = mysql_query( ... )
$result = // resource, boolean or whatever you want
```

Then run the script and calculate the execution time using Coding-Freak's suggestion.

If you prefer Rio Bautista's approach you may find some functions that calculates section's time.